Azure Function App's Custom Domain returns a 403 when IP Restrictions are enabled
I have an Azure function app with a custom domain from an external provider.  The custom domain works fine until I enable IP restrictions.  Once I do, if I hit the custom domain I get a 403 error, but if I hit the .azurewebsites.net url I get the expected response.
I think that this might be something to do with the request being routed through my DNS provider (Cloudflare) but I'm unsure how to resolve it.

As per Set up Azure App Service access restrictions:

When a request is made to your app, the FROM address is evaluated against the rules in your access restriction list. If the FROM address is in a subnet configured with service endpoints to Microsoft.Web, the source subnet is compared against the virtual network rules in your access restriction list.
If the address isn't allowed access based on the rules in the list, the service replies with an HTTP 403 status code.


Hi, thanks for your reply but I'm not sure this answers my question.  I am unsure as to why I get different results when hitting the .azurewebsites.net and my custom domain from the same source IP.  I would have assumed that if, for example, my home router's IP address is in the allow list it would be able to  get a result from both URLs

It seems that adding cloudflare's IP ranges to the allow list solved the problem
